# limit PrintDocumentAdapter to portrait only

Tags: android, printing

Is there any way to limit printing with a PrintDocumentAdapter to portrait ( or landscape ) only. I found out how to react on different orientations but not how to limit to a certain orientation.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you come across with this issue?? Do you have any solution to lock the orientation in portait mode.

Comment: No - I did not find a way to do so

Comment: what did you do to overcome this issue

Comment: Nothing unfortunately - living with this suboptimal UX currently